# Getting result grouped by month in Django

Tags: python, django

I want to get all members from a Member model and get total calculations that they have done per month.

My query is as follows:

```
members_list = Member.objects\
        .exclude(deleted=True) \
        .annotate(num_calculations=Count('user__calculations'))\
        .order_by("-user__date_joined")
```

With this query I get all members and total calculations that they have done.

How can I get total calculations per month(last 12 months)?

Calculation model is as follows:

```
class Calculations(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(to=User)
    make = models.CharField(max_length=127)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=127)        
    mileage = models.IntegerField()        
    price_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    sales_price_currency = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True)
```

And member model is as follows:

```
class Member(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(to=User)
    number = models.CharField(max_length=10)        
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    active = models.BooleanField()
    deleted = models.NullBooleanField(null=True)
```

Comment: which django version and db engine are you using?

Comment: I don't enough experience with these to whip up a working query for you, but I believe you may want to take a look at [conditional expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/conditional-expressions/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve it. In case that someone else needs it here is the solution.

First I got all calculation per month as follows:

```
items = list(Calculations.objects
                     .filter(user__member__number=member_number)
                     .filter(price_date__gte=datetime.datetime.now().today() - relativedelta(months=12))
                     .annotate(date=TruncMonth('price_date'))
                     .values('date')
                     .annotate(total=Count('id'))
                     .values('date', 'total')
                     .order_by('date'))
```

But here I get only months where the user did the calculations, but I need the last 12 months no matter if the user did the calculations in that month or not.

To get that right I did next:

```
result = []
for month in range(12):
     date = timezone.now() - relativedelta(months=month)
     next_month = date + relativedelta(months=1)

     month_results = list(filter(lambda i: date <= i['date'] + relativedelta(months=1) < nextMonth, items))

     month_result = 0

     if month_results:
        month_result = month_results[0]['total']

     result.append({'total_calculations': month_result})
```

That did the trick.